# Updating Pages after migration of website

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

My web site was coded in Coldfusion and over the years has obtained a good ranking.  I recently migrated the front-end to a Wordpress site and wanted to know what is ideal way of updating Google and the various search engines of of the updates.

For example, the home page of `index.cfm` is no longer valid since it's `index.php`. I've submitted an updated `sitemap.xml` file to Google. I'm sure my site will slip some while the search engines re-index my site but I'd like to try and minimize this as much as possible with the holidays coming up (my site is a service oriented site that caters to people who travel during the holidays).

Right now, the old `.cfm` pages are still online but are re-routed to the appropriate Wordpress page (for example, `about.cfm` is now routed to `/about/` using a cflocation tag.).  Not sure if I should pull down the `.cfm` pages all together or leave them in place until the new pages are picked up by the search engines.

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your redirects will remain in place permanently but not for SEO reasons. The search engines will eventually associate tyhe new URLs with the old URLs and update their indexes accordingly. However, users who follow links that lead to the old URLs will get lost if those redirects are removed.

But you're going to want to remove the old CFM pages because they're just sitting there wasting space and creating clutter. So I suggest you go back and put your redirects in an htaccess file so you can have them all in one place and have the ability to remove the no longer needed CFM files.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on a rule to add to the .htaccess file or a resource to help me writing the rule?

Comment: The rule(s) will depend on what the old URL structure was and what the new is. You may be able to write one rule to handle multiple pages. You might have to write one rule for each page. I can't say either way without knowing what the old and new URLs are.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  This helps give me some direction.

Comment: I went back and reread your answer.  Were you suggesting I had a rewrite rule for each .cfm page I have?

Comment: Yes. But if there is a pattern to your new and old page names you should be able to write generic rules to handle multiple pages at once.

Comment: you could also handle all the redirects in Application.cfm allowing you to remove all your old pages. You would still need to specify each one, but thats easy using CGI.SCRIPT_NAME

Comment: @wes I was thinking that, too.  Thanks for confirming.